# Am i adding an integer to a resb wrong? and how to correct?

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

my objective is to create a simple game called Pig. The rules are
2 players (you and the computer) are racing to reach
100 points. Each turn, the active player faces a decision:
a) Hold, take your turn total and add it to the player's overall total.
The next player becomes active.
b) Roll, generate a random number between
1 and 6.
Results are:
o to 1:
Lose turn, no turn total added to overall total.
2 to 6:
Add this number to the turn total. Player goes again.

when i assemble, link, and run i receive:

rogerfleenor@roger-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ ./pig 
Welcome to the Game of Pig.
Objective and Rules: first to 100 wins. Enter 1 to skip your turn and give the pc your score or 2 to roll the dice. If the outcome is 0 or 1, turn lost. If 2 to 6, it is added to your score. Ready? Go!
Enter 1 to skip turn or 2 to roll.
2
2your score is

the first "2" above is the number i entered, the second 2 is generated from "write_digit2:"

which should actually output the random number that was generated. so that leads me
to beleive that my problem resides in "cmpUserDice"and that i am adding the random digit to an
empty buffer wrong or something similar. Especially since when i reach the end of the program
where "userScore" should print, nothing is outputted in the terminal. is anyone able  to identify
my issue? This is my final project and is due in two days! i am very desperate.

```
section .bss

    userScore: resb 4
    pcScore: resb 4

    counter: resb 4
    digiter: resb 4

    number: resb 4
    digit: resb 4
    count:  resb 4  

    userOption: resb 30
    intLen: resd 1

section .data

    welcomeMsg db "Welcome to the Game of Pig.",13,10

    welcomeLen equ $ - welcomeMsg

    ruleMsg dd "Objective and Rules: first to 100 wins. Enter 1 to skip your turn and give the pc your score or 2 to roll the dice. If the outcome is 1, turn lost. If 2 to 6, it is added to your score. Ready? Go!",13,10

    ruleLen equ $ - ruleMsg


    optionMsg db "Enter 1 to skip turn or 2 to roll.",13,10

    optionLen equ $ - optionMsg


    userScoreIs db "your score is",13,10

    userScoreIsLen equ $ - userScoreIs


section .text

    global _start:

_start:

    nop

mov ax, 0

call printWelcome
call printRules
call printReadOption

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h

printWelcome:

    mov edx, welcomeLen
    mov ecx, welcomeMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

printRules:

    mov edx, ruleLen
    mov ecx, ruleMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

printReadOption:

    ;prints option

    mov edx, optionLen
    mov ecx, optionMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h 

    ;reads option & saves as string

    mov edx, 30
    mov ecx, userOption
    mov ebx, 2
    mov eax, 3
    int 80h

    ;save size of string input

    dec eax
    mov dword [intLen], eax

    ;convert string to int

    mov edi, 10
    mov ecx, [intLen]
    mov esi, userOption
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx

    mov bl, [esi]
    cmp bl, '-'
    jne next_check
    inc eax
    inc esi
    dec ecx
    jmp done_sign

    next_check:

    cmp bl, '+'
    jne done_sign
    inc esi
    dec ecx

    done_sign:

    push eax

    l1:
    mov bl, [esi]
    cmp bl, 30h
    ;jb error
    cmp bl, 39h
    ;ja error

    sub bl, 30h
    mul edi; eax=eax*10
    mov bh, 0
    add eax, ebx
    inc esi
    loop l1

    pop ebx
    cmp ebx, 1
    jne compareInput
    neg eax

compareInput:

    cmp eax, 2
    je userRollDice ;jmp to roll dice

    cmp eax, 1  ;jmp to pc turn
    je exit     ;switch to pic turn

userRollDice:   ;randnumgen 0-6

    ;jmp exit

    mov eax, 13
    int 80h
    add eax, 65535
    mov ebx, 30903  
    mul ebx,
    mov edx, 0
    mov ecx, 7
    div ecx

    mov dword[number], edx  ;# to print
    ;call write_number

    call cmpUserDice ;decides 1 - 6 effect

write_number:

L01:
        mov eax, dword[number]
        mov ecx, 0Ah
        cdq
        div ecx ;eax=number/10,edx=number%10
        mov dword[number], eax ;number= number/10
        add edx, 30h ;add 48 (30h) to make a printable character
        push edx ;push edx in to the stack and
        inc dword[count] ;increment count of numbers in the stack
        cmp dword[number], 0 ;if number != 0, loop again
        jne L01

L02:

        pop dword[digit] ;pop the digit from the stack and
        call write_digit ;write it
        dec dword[count] ;decrement the count
        cmp dword[count], 0 ; if count != 0, loop again
        jne L02
        ret

write_digit:    ;Print score

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, digit
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h


cmpUserDice:

    cmp edx, 0
    je userRollDice

    cmp edx, 1
    je printReadOption

    cmp edx, 2
    add dword[userScore], 2
    je printUserScore
    ;call pcTurn

    cmp edx, 3 
    add dword[userScore], 3 
    je printUserScore
    ;call pcTurn

    cmp edx, 4
    add dword[userScore], 4
    je printUserScore
    ;call pcTurn    

    cmp edx, 5
    add dword[userScore], 5
    je printUserScore
    ;call pcTurn

    cmp edx, 6
    add dword[userScore], 6
    je printUserScore
    ;call pcTurn

printUserScore:

        mov eax, dword[userScore]
        mov ecx, 0Ah ;hex for 10
        cdq
        div ecx ;eax=number/10,edx=number%10
        mov dword[userScore], eax ;number= number/10
        add edx, 30h ;add 48 (30h) to make a printable character
        push edx ;push edx in to the stack and
        inc dword[counter] ;increment count of numbers in the stack
        cmp dword[userScore], 0 ;if number != 0, loop again
        jne printUserScore

loop2:

        pop dword[digiter] ;pop the digit from the stack and
        call write_digit2 ;write it
        dec dword[counter] ;decrement the count
        cmp dword[counter], 0 ; if count != 0, loop again
        jne loop2
        ret

write_digit2:   ;Print score

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, digiter
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h

    ;prints your score is:

    ;mov dword[userScore], 2

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, userScoreIs
    mov edx, userScoreIsLen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, userScore
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h 

    call exit;
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single step your code to find where the problem is. One thing I can spot right away, is that you `call write_digit` but that is missing ` ret`.

Comment: Are you sure the *undefined* values in your `.bss` start out at "0" -- i.e., *initialized*?

Comment: @Jongware yes, `.bss` is zero initialized.

Comment: i have found the region where the issue is taking place. and that is that i may be trying to add to my 'userScore' buffer wrong. i dont know if i should convert the number i want to add into string first before i 'add dword [userScore], 3' is this the correct method to do so? because after i try to print my 'userScore' nothing displays as if it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. If input had a minus sign then EAX would be wrong. You need `xor eax,eax` between `push eax` and `l1:`

b. The clearing of BH is either superfluous or not enough! You choose.

c. The *write_digit* routine misses a RET instruction and EDX must be set equal to 1 in stead of 4

```
write_digit:    ;Print score

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, digit
mov edx, 4
int 80h
```

d. Several times you used code like :

```
cmp edx, 2
add dword[userScore], 2
je printUserScore
```

The conditional jump will be based on the outcome of the addition and NOT the compare! That was probably not your intent.